# Erro no uso do método 'is'

Tags: javascript, jquery, método

Estou usando o método `is` para checar se, após um tempo, o mouse esta dentro ou fora de um elemento. Contudo, por algum motivo, está dando o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: AuCon.is is not a function

Parte do código:

```js
let AuCon = document.getElementById('AudioConfig');

AuCon.addEventListener('mouseout', Para);
 
function Para() {
    setTimeout(function(){if(AuCon.is(':hover')){AniVoltar}}, 1000);
}

function AniVoltar()
{
  //Código irrelevante.
}
```

```css
#AudioConfig
{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="AudioConfig">
  <!--Conteudo-->
</div>
```

Nesse código eu fiz literalmente igualzinho estava na [documentação](https://api.jquery.com/is/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está tentando utilizar o método [`is`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) do jQuery em uma interface nativa do navegador. Como essa interface nativa *não* implementa o método `is`, você recebe um erro ao tentar invocar algo que não é uma função.

Vejamos onde o erro é causado:

> ```
> AuCon.is(':hover')
> ```

E, de acordo com esta linha:

> ```
> let AuCon = document.getElementById('AudioConfig');
> ```

A variável `AuCon` foi atribuída com o resultado da chamada à `document.getElementById`. Nesse caso, `AuCon` será um `HTMLElement`, que é o [valor retornado por `getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#return_value).

---

Uma opção para resolver isso seria utilizar a API do jQuery para buscar por esse elemento. Mas será que realmente vale a pena incluir os [30.4kB do jQuery](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=jquery@3.5.1) para isso?

Não! :-) Você pode utilizar o método [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches), que  foi inspirado no `is` do jQuery e já é implementado nativamente por [grande parte dos navegadores](https://caniuse.com/matchesselector).

Um exemplo:

```js
let AuCon = document.getElementById('AudioConfig');

AuCon.addEventListener('mouseout', Para);
 
function Para() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (AuCon.matches(':hover')) {
      AniVoltar()
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function AniVoltar() {
  console.log('Chamou.');
}
```

```css
#AudioConfig {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="AudioConfig">
  <!--Conteudo-->
</div>
```

Veja que o jQuery não foi necessário — tanto é que nem foi incluído no código. :-)

Comment: Ai, obrigado cara, sei nem como te agradecer, sucesso!!!